# updating jsonb column in postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to update a `jsonb` column in PG10.  I noticed that the following works only if there is some value exists in that column for a given record.

```
UPDATE public.mytable SET config = jsonb_set (
    config, '{"data1"}', '{ 
        "text" : "my text"
        }', TRUE) 
WHERE id = 1234;
```

The update is successful only if the column `config` is not null. I don't see any errors when I execute the statement though.

If this column for a given record is empty, I need to do

```
UPDATE public.mytable SET config = '{ 
   "data1" : {     
        "text" : "my text"
        }
    }' 
WHERE id = 1234;
```

So my current strategy is to check for non-null and use first or second method to update the column value.  Is this the right approach?  Why is the value not updated when I use `jsonb_set`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE(config,'{}')`

```
UPDATE mytable SET config = jsonb_set (
    COALESCE(config,'{}'),'{"data1"}', '{ 
        "text" : "my text"
        }', TRUE) 
WHERE id = 1234;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=de96241609fc857ef6216c3551d45ff8)